# execute wp_query on specific page

Tags: php, wordpress

im using a wordpress theme which includes a page builder. With that page builder ive developed a 50/50 div-layout. In the left side ive got a google maps instance and in the right one i wanna use my custom post type staff to show all employees. The problem is that i cant execute php code on a wordpress page, except using a wordpress plugin. But the problem with the plugins ive tested is, that i cant use wordpress functionality like wp_query..is there any solution for that?

thanks in advance.

Comment: simple create a page template for that page and add all your php code to it.. ie: if your page is called "builder" duplicate the page.php in your theme folder and rename it to page-builder.php.

Comment: yeah thanks, 10 minutes after my post i found this solution somwhere in the www, but with that i cant include the desired outcome into one of the boxes ive made with this page builder software..